# Python not able to modify MySQL but user can

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7

Sorry if this question is stupid, I am 2 days into learning `python`

I have been beating my head against a wall trying to understand why my `python` script can run `SELECT` statements but not `UPDATE` or `DELETE` statements.

I believe this would be a `MySQL` issue and not a `Python` issue but I am no longer able to troubleshoot

**pcheck.py**

```
import re
import time
import json
import MySQLdb
import requests
from array import *

conn = MySQLdb.connect([redacted])
cur = conn.cursor()

sql1 = "SELECT pkey,pmeta FROM table1 WHERE proced = 0 LIMIT 1"
cur.execute(sql1)
row = cur.fetchone()
while row is not None:
    print "row is: ",row[0]
    rchk = [
     r"(SHA256|MD5)",
     r"(abc|def)"
     ]
    for trigger in rchk:
        regexp = re.compile(trigger)
        pval = row[1]
        if regexp.search(pval) is not None:
            print "matched on: ",row[0]
            sql2 = """INSERT INTO table2 (drule,dval,dmeta) VALUES('%s', '%s', '%s')"""
            try:
                args2 = (trigger, pval, row[1])
                cur.execute(sql2, args2)
                print(cur._last_executed)
            except UnicodeError:
                print "pass-uni"
            break
    else:
        pass

    sql3 = """UPDATE table1 SET proced=1 WHERE pkey=%s"""
    args3 = row[0]
    cur.execute(sql3, args3)
    print(cur._last_executed)
    row = cur.fetchone()

sql3 = """DELETE FROM table1 WHERE proced=1 AND last_update < (NOW() - INTERVAL 6 MINUTE)"""
cur.execute(sql3)
print(cur._last_executed)
cur.close()
conn.close()
print "Finished"
```

And the actual (and suprisingly expected) output:

**OUTPUT**

```
scrape@:~/python$ python pcheck.py 
row is:  0GqQ0d6B
UPDATE table1 SET proced=1 WHERE pkey='0GqQ0d6B'
DELETE FROM table1 WHERE proced=1 AND last_update < (NOW() - INTERVAL 6 MINUTE)
Finished
```

However, the database is not being UPDATED. I checked that the query was making it to MySQL:

**MySQL Log**

```
"2015-12-14 22:53:56","localhost []","110","0","Query","SELECT `pkey`,`pmeta` FROM `table1` WHERE `proced`=0 LIMIT 200"
"2015-12-14 22:53:57","localhost []","110","0","Query","UPDATE `table1` SET `proced`=1 WHERE `pkey`='0GqQ0d6B'"
"2015-12-14 22:53:57","localhost []","110","0","Query","DELETE FROM table1 WHERE proced=1 AND last_update < (NOW() - INTERVAL 6 MINUTE)"
```

However `proced` value for row 0GqQ0d6B is still NOT 1

If I make the same queries via Sqlyog (logged in as user) the queries work as expected.

Comment: Commit the cursor after making changes.

Comment: Make your SQL query a Unicode string to reduce UnicodeExceptions: `u"""INSERT INTO table2 (drule,dval,dmeta) VALUES('%s', '%s', '%s')"""`

Comment: @BobDylan that worked so perfectly. Do I always `commit` the `cursor` after any modification?

Comment: @HydraIO yes, you should, or configure auto-commits (many ORMs do this)

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack I also used the `Unicode` trick and definitely see an improvement on those exceptions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the commenter Bob Dylan was able to deduce the cursor needed to be committed after the change.

Answer (score 0):

These kind of issues can be very frustrating.  You sure there's no extra spaces here?

```
print "row is:*"+row[0]+"*"
```

Perhaps comment out the

```
for trigger in rchk:
```

section, and sprinkle some print statements around?

Comment: Thank you for giving me another possible test case!